# How to force close jQuery UI accordion <DIV> with <asp:button>?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI accordion with two divs. The first displays a form and the second shows data based on the input of the form. How do I auto close the first div and display the second when a user clicks the submit button in the form? I'm assuming I need to use 'onclick' in the button, but I'm not sure how to tie it in with the accordion.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/jscript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#accordion").accordion();
});
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div id="accordion">
<a href="#">Criteria</a>
<div>
<asp:Button ID="Button_GetReport" runat="server" Text="View Report" />
</div>
<a href="#">Report</a>
<div>
A databound grid goes here.
</div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

If I left anything out, let me know. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the submit button would roundtrip to the server, so onclick isn't going to help you. You'll probably want to output whether the accordion should be opened or closed.

One way to do that would be to change your accordion div to have a class showing the state:

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-<%= accordion_state %>"> //open or closed
```

Then your selector would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".accordion_open").accordion();
  $(".accordion_closed").hide();
});
```

See [this article](http://www.dotnetsteve.com/index.php/2010/02/simple-accordion-menu-with-jquery-asp-net/) for some examples of using ASP.NET and the accordion control together.