# .toggle() a div with asp:button

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, postback

I have a basic div that I want to .toggle() OnClientClick of an asp:button. It works as far as the code goes but I think that the OnClick event handler on the server side is causing the div to reset after it is clicked. Basically what happens is the div disappears for about .01ms and then reappears right away. Here is the simplest code example of my problem.

Here is an example of what happens:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ToggleMe() {
            $('#toggleMe').toggle();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="toggleMe">
            <label>Hello World</label>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="ToggleMe();"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried .removeClass, .addClass, .css... I don't think it's as much an issue with the jQuery that I am using as it is with the postback that happens on the button click.

I am running Chrome to test this if that matters.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: you might want to use a jquery `click` function instead of `OnClientClick` and `return false` if u want the client click to be executed first : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453985/how-to-trigger-onclick-and-onclientclick-events-simultaneously-in-asp-net-when-u

Comment: Do you actually require the postback to happen when you click the button?

Comment: PassionateCode: I believe the JavaScript was being executed first but the DOM resets after the server side code runs and returns. Excommunicated: Yeah it has to happen. I decided to go with the solution at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405746/how-to-force-close-jquery-ui-accordion-div-with-aspbutton?rq=1 Thanks to both of you for trying to help me out!

Answer (score 4):

The javascript part of your HTML executes in the user's browser. The protected void button1_click method executes on the server. What is happening is that the user's browser will toggle the div correctly, causing it to disappear. Unfortunately, the HTML of the ASP.NET button will then resubmit the page, meaning the browser refreshes the HTML from your server. The server has no concept of the toggle happening because the javascript did not execute there, and while int i is set to 5, the div gets re-set to being visible after the page refreshes after going to your server. Your options are:

1) don't use any server side logic for the button click, and get rid of

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" ... />
```

and replace it with

```
<input type="button" onclick="ToggleMe();">your text</input>
```

and handle all of your client side logic in your javascript. If you need to set int i = 5 on the server, use JQuery.Ajax to talk back to the server.

2) use only server side .NET to do this. This is implemented like so:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="toggleMe" runat="server">
            <label>Hello World</label>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 5;
    toggleMe.Visible = !toggleMe.Visible;
}
```

Comment: These are some great solutions! Thanks for answering!

Comment: Also thanks for verifying my hypothesis about what was happening!

Answer (score 1):

when u click the aspx:Button, it submits the page. it is much easier if you use regular html button

```
<input type="button" onclick="ToggleMe()">Button</input>
```

and please add a "return false;" statement to your code below

```
function ToggleMe() {
   $('#toggleMe').toggle();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: It's easier but not correct for my purposes :( Thanks anyway!